# Why is Javascript returning "undefined" in Switch statement?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I'm doing a Javascript exercise to learn Switch Statement and I can't find where is the error (actually I can't understand why it's returning "undefined").
I've tried:

```
var myNumber = document.querySelector(".myNumber").value;
```

but didn't work.
I've tried insert a **case 0**, it didn't work.

```js
  
    var printNumber = document.getElementById("numresult").innerHTML = printNumber;
    var myNumber = document.querySelector(".myNumber").textContent;
    
    switch(myNumber) {
        case 1:
            printNumber = "You got 1";
            break;
         case 2:
            printNumber = "You got 2";
            break;           
        case 3:
            printNumber = "You got 3";
            break;
        case 4:
            printNumber = "You got 4";
            break;
        case 5:
            printNumber = "You got 5";
            break;
        case 6:
            printNumber = "You got 6";
            break;
        case 7:
            printNumber = "You got 7";
            break;
        case 8:
            printNumber = "You got 8";
            break;
        case 9:
            printNumber = "You got 9";
            break;
        default:
            printNumber = "Oops";
    }
```

```html
<p class="myNumber">1</p>
<p id="numresult"></p>
```

Comment: You're reading the value **from** `printNumber` (and assigning it to `innerHTML`) **before** you assign a value **to** `printNumber` in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing strings with numbers.

`value` returns a string and `switch` works with strict comparison `===`.

Finally, you need to assign the value to the element.

```
document.getElementById("numresult").innerHTML = printNumber;
```

```js
var printNumber,
    myNumber = +document.querySelector(".myNumber").textContent;
    //         ^ unary plus to convert string to number

switch (myNumber) {
    case 1:
        printNumber = "You got 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        printNumber = "You got 2";
        break;
    case 3:
        printNumber = "You got 3";
        break;
    case 4:
        printNumber = "You got 4";
        break;
    case 5:
        printNumber = "You got 5";
        break;
    case 6:
        printNumber = "You got 6";
        break;
    case 7:
        printNumber = "You got 7";
        break;
    case 8:
        printNumber = "You got 8";
        break;
    case 9:
        printNumber = "You got 9";
        break;
    default:
        printNumber = "Oops";
}

document.getElementById("numresult").innerHTML = printNumber;
```

```html
<p class="myNumber">1</p>
<p id="numresult"></p>
```

Comment: If that was the (immediate) problem it would read `Oops` not `undefined`